# JSON object treated as string in Flask app

Tags: jquery, python, json

Taking my first steps in javascript with a Flask app (a dice game): I have a function returning some python objects. I want to render the object values on a page to use with javascript animations.

Using json.dumps and then jsonify in python I managed to pass and render what looks like a JSON object. Final output on the page looks like this:

```
{"dice1": {"value": 5, "status": "unlocked"}}
```

It looks pretty, the quotation marks are all in the right place and when I check this on JSLint it seems to be legit JSON material. As intended, I am able to get new object values from the function when clicking a button.

But when I try to access the values with the key it returns "undefined":

```
document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = data.data.dice1
```

The only thing I seem to be able to do is to access element using bracket, like this :

```
document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = data.data[0]
```

I'm not sure where I'm messing up. I've tried adding JSON.parse() in javascript but it returns an error. I changed the mimetype to application/json but it didn't help.

Do I need an additional step to convert this string (?) into real JSON? Is the problem coming from the combination of jsonify and json.dumps?

```
import json
from flask import render_template, jsonify


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    python_object(object)
    data = json.dumps({"dice1":{"value":d1.value,"status":d1.status}})

    if request.is_xhr:
        return jsonify(data=data)


    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('main.html',data=data,status=200, 
        mimetype='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

html

```
 $(function() {
                $('#roll-button').click(function() {
                    $.get('/', function(data){
                    document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = 
                    data.data
                })

            });

        });
```

Comment: It's useful here to include `console.log(typeof data)` and `console.dir(data)` in your JS to see what is actually being passed in.

Comment: Thanks, the log returns Object
data
:
"{"dice1": {"value": 2, "status": "unlocked"}}"
__proto__
:
Object. Should I see JSON ?

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = data.dice1`

Comment: Just tried this but it returns 'undefined'